# Canceled operation is still running

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I need to cancel all operation in operationqueue. but after call cancellAllOperation method, operations is still running.
simple example:

```
@interface MyOperation : NSOperation
@end
@implementation MyOperation
-(void)main {
  NSLog(@"starting 1");
  sleep(4);
  NSLog(@"finished 1");
}
@end
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
   MyOperation *op = [MyOperation new];
   [queue addOperation:op];
   sleep(2);
   [queue cancelAllOperations];
   NSLog(@"canceled");
}
log:
2014-07-23 09:55:48.839 MDict1[837:1303] starting 1
2014-07-23 09:55:50.842 MDict1[837:70b] canceled
2014-07-23 09:55:52.842 MDict1[837:1303] finished 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canceling an operation won't wake up the `sleep` call. And calling `sleep` in `viewDidLoad` is BAD. Never sleep on the main thread.

The proper solution is that the implementation of your operation's `main` method needs to check if `self` has been cancelled. If so, it needs to return.

One rough example might be:

```
- (void)main {
    while (!self.isCancelled) {
        // do some repeated operation
    }
}
```

Again, it is the responsibility of the operation to stop itself when it sees that it has been cancelled. The queue doesn't actually kill any operations.

From the docs for `NSOperationQueue cancelAllOperations` (emphasis mine):

> This method sends a cancel message to all operations currently in the queue. Queued operations are cancelled before they begin executing. **If an operation is already executing, it is up to that operation to recognize the cancellation and stop what it is doing.**

Comment: that mean I have to check isCancelled property before do any thing?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt but most if the operation is cancelled before it starts, `main` won't be called.